# Extended slicing in python with 3 args

Tags: python, list, slice

I am trying to understand slicing. How does this slice work?

```
>>> a=['c','b']
>>> a
['c', 'b']
>>> a[-3:-1:3]
['c']
```

I have already read all the posts and cannot find an answer. As I understand it slice is supposed to be `[start:stop:step]`. But if I start at -3 after one step I am at 0.
How exactly does this work? Which indexes are printed? The ones in the range?

Comment: Have you read the Python documentation on slicing? In the most basic case, it goes from `start` to `stop` in increments of `step`, excluding `stop`, but it gets a bit more complicated than that in some cases.

Comment: Your problems appears to be with `start` and `stop`, not `step`. Negative start and stop indices count from the end (in a manner too complicated for me to reproduce faithfully in a comment).

Answer (score 1):

First note that `a[-3:-1]` is  `['c']`. 
`a[-3:-1]` is a slice containing all the elements in `[a[-3], a[-2]]`, (if they exist).

```
>>> a=['c','b']
>>> a[-3:-1]
['c']
```

`a[-3]` does not exist (it raises an IndexError), but `a[-2]` is `'c'`:

```
>>> a[-2]
'c'
```

That makes sense, since `a[-1]` is the last element, `'b'`. `a[-2]` is thus the penultimate element.

Finally,

```
>>> a[-3:-1:3]
['c']
```

since this is every third element in `a[-3:-1]`. Since there is only one element in `a[-3:-1]`, every third element is the same as the first and only element.

The exact rules governing slicing is given by [Notes 3 and 5 of the docs section entitled "Common Sequence Operations"](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations).

Answer (score 1):

Think of the indexes as dividers right after an element. e.g.

Given list `['a', 'b', 'c']`

Positive indexes (indexes in |n|): `['a'|0| 'b'|1| 'c'|2|]`

Negative indexes (indexes in |n|), I'm gonna show the list in reverse so it's a bit more clear: `['c'|-1| 'b'|-2| 'a'|-3|]` or in the original direction (but think of it starting from the end) `[|-3|'a' |-2|'b' |-1|'c']`

So in your example: `a=['c','b']` your negative indexes are `[|-2|'c' |-1|'b']` but when you're doing a range, Python doesn't complain when you pass an out of scope starting index of `-3`. In fact you can pass in any arbitrary indexes when you do a range and Python won't complain. Try for example `[-10:-5]`, but because in your case your range does contain `'c'`, that's all you get.